# Recursive SQL Query or Just Multiple Unions? Or Something Else?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query grabbing data from 5 different tables.  To return records for every date and every account, I have to create a 'master' table with date and account id.

Since I really don't have a reference table for the account_id, I was thinking of writing the query as such.

```
select tab1.calendar_date, tab1.cal_d, (0) as account_id from calendar.table
union all
select tab1.calendar_date, tab1.cal_d, (1) as account_id from calendar.table
union all
select tab1.calendar_date, tab1.cal_d, (2) as account_id from calendar.table
```

and so on to account id 5.

The resulting table is then mapped to 5 other tables to pull the other information.  Is there another way for me to restructure this query so it's not doing 4/5 joins?  A co-worker suggested a recursive table, but I'm not familiar with it.  I'm almost referencing as the master 'fact' table.

Additional context.  I need the resulting table to look like the following:

```
calendar_date_id     calendar_date     account_id
2766                 2014-01-01        1
2766                 2014-01-01        2
2766                 2014-01-01        3
...                  2014-01-01        6
```

After this table/result is generated, I will join it with other tables with other metrics/dimensions.

Comment: it looks like you are doing something wrong here, but impossible to tell unless you post sample of data in those tables

Comment: Your query is similar to creating a table with one column and holding 3 rows (0,1,2) and making a cross join with your tab1. It's no clear what you got and what do you want. Please post some more elaborate examples (try using SQL Fiddle).

Comment: Brett's response worked the way I needed it to.  I just realized that the resulting query is not supported by Tableau's custom sql so the solution is moot in that environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest doing the zero to five thing using a recursive cte like so:

```
with zerotofive as (
  select 0 as a
  union all
  select a+1 as a from zerotofive
   where a<5
)
select tab1.calendar_date, tab1.cal_d, zerotofive.a as account_id 
  from calendar.table
 cross join
       zerotofive
```

and then join that with any other tables you may have

Answer (score 0):

USE [Recursive Common Table Expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) like

```
;WITH  CTEmaster AS(
select tab1.calendar_date, tab1.cal_d, 0 as account_id from calendar.table
union all
select tab1.calendar_date, tab1.cal_d, account_id+1 as account_id from CTEmaster
where account_id<5
)
select * from CTEmaster join (to your desired tables )
```